# Tweepy check if user A is following user B?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have this code (not all of the code) and it basically gets the 20 most recent followers. The problem is that it will make a follow request to people who I am already following. This wouldn't be a problem but twitter limits how many requests you can make.

```
followers = api.followers()
following = api.friends()
tofollow = [x for x in followers if x not in following]
for u in tofollow:
   try:
      u.follow()
      number_followed+=1
      print number_followed,". ", u.screen_name
   except tweepy.TweepError as err:
    print "Error: when following ", u.screen_name
```

i think it has something to do with when i make tofollow

any thoughts?

Comment: what are following and followers? Are you sure they both return users in the same format?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to make twitter queries for the whole set and not for 20 most recent, you should use a cursor.

For example:

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items()
```

Also if you don't want to violate the twitter rate limiting you could use the following line when initializing the api object:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

Hope it helps. Here is an example:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

friends = api.friends_ids(api.me().id)
print("You follow", len(friends), "users")

for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    if follower.id != api.me().id:
        if follower.id in friends:
            print("You already follow", follower.screen_name)
        else:
            follower.follow()
            print("Started following", follower.screen_name)
```